# Why do I need to declare the type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code:

```
public interface IMyActionFactory
{
    AbstractAction<T> CreateAction<T>(MyActionParamBase paramBase = null)
        where T : MyActionParamBase;
}

public sealed class MergeActionParam : MyActionParamBase
{
}

public class MergeTest
{
    private readonly IMyActionFactory _actionFactory = new DefaultMyActionFactory();

    [Theory]
    [PropertyData("MergeWorksData")]
    public void MergeWorks(/*params here*/)
    {
        var param = new MergeActionParam();
        // populate param here

        var sut = _actionFactory.CreateAction<MergeActionParam>(param);
        sut.DoAction();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error

> "..Error  10  Using the generic type 'IMyActionFactory' requires 1
>   type arguments..."

Why does the compiler expect a type to be passed to my IMyActionFactory, since I have declared the interface without a T? As far as the method is concerned its the only one to expect the type. Am I missing something here?

How can I make it work without redefining the interface signature?

**EDIT:**
Feeling a bit embarassed here, because the quick code I put down and ran seperately in a standalone online c# compiler doesnt give any compilation errors. However, going back to my original solution (tens of projects altogether) the error is still there.. Maybe has something to do with the XUnit ?..not sure

```
public interface IMyActionFactory
{
    AbstractAction<T> CreateAction<T>(MyActionParamBase paramBase = null)
        where T : MyActionParamBase;
}

public interface IAction
    {
        void DoAction();
    }

 public abstract class AbstractAction<T> : IAction
        where T : MyActionParamBase
    {
        public void DoAction()
        {
        }
}

public class MyActionParamBase
    {

        public MyActionParamBase()
        {
        }
    }

public sealed class MergeActionParam : MyActionParamBase
{
}

public class DefaultMyActionFactory : IMyActionFactory
    {
        public AbstractAction<T> CreateAction<T>(MyActionParamBase paramBase = null) where T : MyActionParamBase
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

public class MergeTest
{
    private readonly IMyActionFactory _actionFactory = new DefaultMyActionFactory();


    public void MergeWorks(/*params here*/)
    {
        var param = new MergeActionParam();
        // populate param here

        var sut = _actionFactory.CreateAction<MergeActionParam>(param);
        sut.DoAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should provide a complete, minimal, working example. Right now there are too many compiler errors when I try to run your code to be able to help.

Comment: It works fine for me (although I have to say that your code implies that you're not quite using generics to their full power). You need to provide a minimal example that actually produces the issue you're expecting. The error message doesn't make any sense - if `IMyActionFactory` was generic, it would show something like `IMyActionFactory<T>`.

Comment: When I flesh out what I think the rest of the code should be it compiles without error. We really need to see the rest of your code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Do you mean you want `AbstractAction<T> CreateAction<T>(MyActionParamBase paramBase)
        where T : MyActionParamBase;` to infer `T` based on `paramBase`'s type? Then change it to `CreateAction<T>(T paramBase)`...

Comment: @Luaan - You shouldn't edit someone else's question like that. Let FatGiant do the editing.

Comment: Ok thanks, let me make some changes to remove the xunit related stuff and will be back